# Ionic3 routing with multiple root components

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I have an Ionic application where some pages require login and some pages don't. When user is logged in, I want to show the menu, when not logged in, user should see the page without the menu. For this, we use two root components: SecurePage and PublicPage. SecurePage has the menu and PublicPage doesn't. ProductList page requires login and needs to be rendered inside the SecurePage. In the app.ts we set the root page depending on if the user has an access token or not:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.translateService.addLangs(["en", "nl"]);
    this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en');

    this.authService.getAccessToken()
      .flatMap((access_token) => {
        if (access_token)
          return this.springApiService.isTokenValid(access_token);
        else
          return Observable.of(false)
      })
      .subscribe(isTokenValid => {

        if (isTokenValid)
          this.rootPage = SecurePage;
        else
          this.rootPage = PublicPage;
      });

  }
```

And then in `SecurePage.ts` there is:

```
  ionViewCanEnter(): Promise<boolean> {

    return this.authService.getPrincipal()
      .map(principal => {
        this.principal = principal;
        this.hasRoleSuperuser = this.authService.hasRoleSuperuser;
        this.hasRoleSales = this.authService.hasRoleSales;
        this.hasRoleAccountant = this.authService.hasRoleAccountant;
        this.hasRoleManager = this.authService.hasRoleManager;
        this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
        this.navCtrl.popAll()
          .then(() => this.navCtrl.setRoot('TodoListComponent'));
        return true;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return Observable.of(false);
      }).toPromise();

  }
```

And `ProductList` has:

```
@IonicPage({
  segment: 'product-list'
})
```

It all works fine when navigating from the menu. But if the page is refreshed while viewing the product list, the behavior is unpredictable. Sometimes it does route to the product list again which is what I want. But most of the time secure page is loaded after the product list therefore the

```
this.navCtrl.popAll()
          .then(() => this.navCtrl.setRoot('TodoListComponent'));
```

line kicks in last so it routes to to do list instead of the product list. How can I make sure that the routing kicks in after the root page is set? Or is there another approach where I can implement the multiple masterpage logic and the routing works fine?